# How to edit signup-config.xml in the wso2 api manager registry?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to get started with the WSO2 API manager.  I changed the admin password from the default, and am slowly working my way through all the places it seems to get embedded.  The latest issue is that when I try to self-register in the store, I get:

Unable to add a user. Please check credentials in the signup-config.xml in the registry

What is this registry, and how do I get to signup-config.xml to edit the admin password?

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to registry resource through admin console.
access admin console in following url
https://localhost:9443/carbon

then in the main tab you can find a section called Resources .There click on browse link . this will take you to browse the resources in registry.
you can find the sign-up-config.xml in the following location by browsing

```
/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/sign-up-config.xml
```

there you need to change the admin password